# Animated gifs in posts

Tags: discussion

Recently, I have seen several questions with animated gifs being edited to contain only the link to the images.

I understand that too many animated gifs can cause high CPU load for people with old computer and choke the connection for people with limited bandwidth.

However, the questions look quite bad, since it consists of only 1-2 lines of text with the link to the picture.

So I have thought up a few solutions to this problem:

- Take a notable frame of the animated gif and put it up

  **Effort gauge:** Use a tool to view and extract a good frame from the gif and upload it.
- Include one (or more) animated gif, as long as the total size of the images do not exceed a threshold

  **Effort gauge:** Check the size of the image (can be done easily in Firefox, outside incognito mode, not sure for other browsers).
- (Your solution?)

Or maybe leaving the post barren is not a problem in the first place? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Images should not be the main part of the question. If all you can do is ask your question with an image to begin with, it's not a good question (Yes, that refers to [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions as well).

If your question consists of one line with an image, it should probably be closed anyway.

What's the solution? Write more. The image should only be an added value, not the main thing.

If imgur drops dead tomorrow, your post should still stand, even if it doesn't look as pretty.

---

TL;DR - I don't think there's anything that needs doing on that part. We just need better written questions, regardless of the images in it.

Comment: I don't understand what else an asker can add to a question when what they have is only an image. Sometimes, the image comes from some image site without context, so it's the only thing the asker has. It's not a good question, but nothing can be improved about it.

Comment: @nhahtdh TBH a question with less details is still a weaker question. If someone wants to ask "What character/item/thing is in this picture that I randomly found", then that makes for a very uneventful question that is likely no help to anyone but the person asking the question. All-in-all a rather bad question.

Comment: If imgur drops dead tomorrow, Stack Exchange still has backups of the images stored on their account, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124988/. While they'd need to find a new place to host them, it's pretty safe to say that this would happen relatively quickly. So to me, it makes more sense to view images uploaded to Stack Exchange's imgur as permanent parts of the post on the same level as the text, rather than as bonus content that could disappear at any time the same way links could.

Comment: @Thebluefish: I think it would help people who find the image via reverse image search, great question or not. (I don't think they are great question, but they are the best they can ever be, since nothing can possibly be added to make them better). Though for animated gif's case, I don't know if it helps that much.